# $f''$ has a double root, what does it say about $f$?

Tags: derivatives

Condider that $f''$ has a double root, what can be concluded of $f$? 
I mean is there any clue of how it acts on that particular point? Does it always happen at maximum or minimum?

Comment: Consider, say, $f(x)=x^3$.  Then $f'(x)=3x^2$ has a double root at $0$ but $0$ is neither a max nor a min for $f(x)$.

Comment: well,if you think about [Rolle's theorm](https://www.britannica.com/science/Rolles-theorem), if $f''$ has $2$ roots, then $f'$ itself must have 3 and $f$ , $4$

Answer (score 0):

Not always, Let f"=12x^2 so f =x^4 +cx+d, as you can see f" has a double root in x=0, but f has a minimum or maximum in x=0 if c=0

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the root is repeated is not so important as the fact that $f''$ vanishes there. In that case, provided $f''(x+\mathrm dx)$ changes sign according as $\mathrm dx\ne 0$ changes sign across the vanishing point, then we conclude that there is a point of inflexion of $f$ there -- that is, a swap in concavity.